# PDO Drivers not installed on XXAMP error, even after uncommenting out the MySQL.dll extension to enable it

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, xampp

I am trying to connect to a remote device , PLC (programmable logic controller) through WAMP, but for some reason I get this error when I load the file in the browser

This is the error mesageFatal error:

> Uncaught PDOException: could not find driver in
>   D:\xxamp\htdocs\REMOTE_BOOSTER\getPLC.php:5 Stack trace: #0
>   D:\xxamp\htdocs\REMOTE_BOOSTER\getPLC.php(5):
>   PDO->__construct('sqlsrv:Server=B...', 'user', 'password') #1 {main}
>   thrown in D:\xxamp\htdocs\REMOTE_BOOSTER\getPLC.php on line 5

I tried uncommenting out the MySQL drivers to enable them, but all in vain

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: could not find driver in
>   D:\xxamp\htdocs\REMOTE_BOOSTER\getPLC.php:5 Stack trace: #0
>   D:\xxamp\htdocs\REMOTE_BOOSTER\getPLC.php(5):
>   PDO->__construct('sqlsrv:Server=B...', 'sa', 'admin,2017') #1 {main}
>   thrown in D:\xxamp\htdocs\REMOTE_BOOSTER\getPLC.php on line 5

This is the error mesageFatal error:

> Uncaught PDOException: could not find driver in
>   D:\xxamp\htdocs\REMOTE_BOOSTER\getPLC.php:5 Stack trace: #0
>   D:\xxamp\htdocs\REMOTE_BOOSTER\getPLC.php(5):
>   PDO->__construct('sqlsrv:Server=B...', 'user', 'password') #1 {main}
>   thrown in D:\xxamp\htdocs\REMOTE_BOOSTER\getPLC.php on line 5

Comment: what about both `php_pdo.dll` and  `php_pdo_mysql.dll` ?

Comment: Still does not work.